# How to return fields in Spring Boot that is not present in the model?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

So I have a use case where I want to return a particular attribute for all the rows of a table. But the attribute does not exist in the table. It should be generated on the fly.

For example - A table called `Student` - has the following attribute 
* ID
* Name

Now, when I use the repository for this model class, I want to return all the rows of data including `ID` and `Name` but also append another property called `URL` along with each row. So output will be -

- ID
- Name
- URL

The data for the `URL` can be generated on the fly - say = `"example.com/"+ID`

How shall I proceed ?

The same model/Repository/Service class for this entity are as follows -

Entity Student

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class StudentDetail {

            @Id
            private Long ID;
            private String Name; 

    }
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface StudentDetail  extends JpaRepository<StudentDetail , Integer> {

}
```

Service

```
@Override
    public List<StudentDetail> getStudentDetails() {
        List<StudentDetail> studentDetail = studentDetailsRepository.findAll();
        return studentDetail;
    }
```

The service will return all the rows with only `ID` and `Name` attribute. How do I calculate the URL parameter in repository ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a transient field (it means, it won't be mapped to any column and persisted):

```
public class StudentDetail {

        @Id
        private Long ID;
        private String Name;
        @Transient
        private String url = // Here comes your implementation

}
```

Comment: 1. Will the service call return the url value since it is not persisted ? 
2. Is it possible to move this url logic in the repository layer instead of the Entity itself ?

Comment: 1. Yes, it will be returned and not persisted, 2. maybe, but I'm not sure how to do it and that's not what's repository is for, if you really don't want it to be in entity, you might map the entity to DTO in `@Service`

Comment: Okay so the url property does show up but it is not able to add the ID to it . URL is defined as - private String url ="example.com"+ID. I tried with 'this' reference as well. However, ID shows up NULL

Comment: You might need to use `@PostConstruct`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Just a note - Since I am using @PostConstruct, I have to manually define the getter for the URL parameter and inside it define its value. The advantages of lombok are lost for this property

Comment: @BoudhayanDev yes, or setting it in post construct should also work, no problem, if it helps, consider upvoting / marking as correct ;>